# Read only alphabets of a txt file containg blankspaces and numbers as well in c

Tags: c

I have a question about reading names(alphabets) from a txt file(directory.txt) containing spaces as well as numbers. After that by dynamic memory allocate space.

**Input File:**
It has 50 names just given some for reference.

80043   CHEBIYYAM
80131   SHUKLA
80200   GANGARAPU
85400   GAURAV

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define telenum 50

char **readnames ( char fname[], int n )
{
   FILE *fp;
   int i, l;
   char **A, buf[1024];

   fp = (FILE *)fopen(fname,"r");
   if (fp == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to open file...\n");
      n = 0;
      return NULL;
   }

   A = (char **)malloc((n) * sizeof(char *));
   for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      while (getc(fp) != '\n');
      fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
      l = strlen(buf);
      A[i] = (char *)malloc((l+1) * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(A[i],buf);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return A;
}

void printnames ( char **A, int n )
{
   int i;

   for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
     printf("%s\n", A[i]);
     free(A[i]);
   }
   free(A);
}

int main ()
{
   char **names;
   names = readnames("directory.txt",telenum);
   printnames(names,telenum);
}
```

I am getting random output not the desired one.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could just answer this changing a lot of the original code, but I think that I'll help more if I give you some tips.

1. Maybe the most important: Name your variables, describe what they do. This will turn easier to find your bug, and the community understand you code! :-D

   What is `A`, `n`, `telenum`, `l`? Will be easier to read your code if you write the meaning of them ;-)
2. In the `for` in `readnames` function. You have a `while(getc(fp) != '\n')`

   When you call `getc`, you get one character of the file. When you run this line, you're saying to computer: "Hey, drop the line I read since the `for` loop started away, I don't need it!"

   When you get one character of the file, the file offset will go to the next character to you read it, then... you're reading the first character, then the next character, and the next.... till it is a '\n'. And... losing where you were.
3. The `fscanf` with the `%s` is [an insecure function](https://rules.sonarsource.com/c/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-1079) and you would need to do some tricks to read the whole line if you want to.

   I suggest you to change this:

   ```c
   while (getc(fp) != '\n');
   fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
   ```

   for this:

   ```c
   // Read the full line (including the '\n')
   fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp);
   ```
4. Your buffer must be cleaned before you reuse it.

   - Let's imagine a pretty small buffer with 10 characters:

   `['\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0']`

   - Then, you read one number (10) and a name (Emma):

   `['1', '0', ' ', 'E', 'm', 'm', 'a', '\n', '\0', '\0']`

   - Nice! Now, you read a smaller number (5) and another name (Dix)

   `['5', ' ', 'D', 'i', 'x', '\n', 'a', '\n', '\0', '\0']`

   - Yey! Now I have a lot of trash, and I have no idead what is the name I just read. Also, I have 2 lines \o/

   To avoid this, always remember to overwrite your whole buffer with something (usually '\0')

   You can do this overwrite including this line: `memset(buf, '\0', MAX_LINE_SIZE)`
5. After is all OK getting the whole line, you need to remove the '\n'. You can do this overwriting the character on `strlen(buf) - 1`. Remember to update the length of the buffer if you want to store it in some variable.
6. There was a lot of work till here, after getting the line, removing the \n and the whole stuff above, you'll get one string in format `1354564 SOMENAME` (by the examples you gave).

   Now its easy, you can use a `sscanf` and extract the info you need. And if you don't know how to do it, [here is an easy to follow tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm)

---

And Now... the code (with a lot of prints and comments)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define telenum 50

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1024

void extractNameFromBuffer(char *buffer)
{
    int trash;
    char extractorBuffer[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    // Separate the string and throw the number away
    sscanf(buffer, "%d %s", &trash, extractorBuffer);

    // clear buffer to store the fresh-new name!
    memset(buffer, '\0', MAX_LINE_SIZE);

    // Now, store the gotten name into the buffer
    memcpy(buffer, extractorBuffer, strlen(extractorBuffer));
}

char **readNames ( char fileName[], int amountOfLines )
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int i = 0, lineLength = 0;
    char **names, buffer[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to open file...\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    names = (char **)malloc((amountOfLines) * sizeof(char *));

    for(i=0; i<amountOfLines; i++) {
        // Clean the buffer before read a new line
        memset(buffer, '\0', MAX_LINE_SIZE);

        // Read the complete line, including spaces and \n's
        fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp);

        // If read nothing this time
        if(buffer[0] == '\0') {
            printf("This line is blank or does not exist, trying next line\n");

        } else {
            // Calculate the lenth of the line (including \n and special/blank characters)
            lineLength = strlen(buffer);

            // Overwrite the \n with a \0, removing the \n of the buffer
            buffer[lineLength - 1] = '\0';

            // Here we have the "165156 SOMENAME" strings

            // Separate name from number
            extractNameFromBuffer(buffer);

            // Here we have the "SOMENAME" string, already!

            // Updates lineLength (now we don't have the \n)
            lineLength = strlen(buffer);

            // Allocate memory to hold the name
            names[i] = (char *)malloc( (lineLength + 1) * sizeof(char) );

            // Copy the name to the new memory space
            strcpy(names[i], buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return names;
}

void printNames ( char **names, int amountOfLines )
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<amountOfLines; i++) {
        if(names[i] != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", names[i]);
            free(names[i]);
        } else {
            printf("No names names[%d] space\n", i);
        }
    }

    free(names);
}

int main ()
{
    char **names = NULL;
    names = readNames("directory.txt",telenum);
    printNames(names,telenum);
}
```

With a file with exactly 50 lines, this the end of my output:

[image: last lines of output]

With a file with 48 lines (missing 2 lines from 50), this is the end of output, as expected:

[image: when missing 2 lines this was the end of my output]

Hope this helps! Have fun!

Comment: 1. A is a new array on which dynamic memory allocation is performed, telenum is the number of entries which in  our case is 50.

Comment: I couldn't get the desired result even after the modifications. Please could you send the code you are talking about. Also considering the fact that we have to ignore the numbers just have to read the name. As in your example (1354564 SOMENAME) we have to read only SOMENAME.

Comment: Nice, I've just updated and posted the code. Any doubts, you're free to ask. Have fun!

Comment: The output is as follows :                                                                                         This line is blank or does not exist, trying next line *50
CHEBIYYAM
No names names[1] space *50                                                                                         It doesn't read the next line.

Comment: This code is expecting a file in the format: "15654565 SOMENAME\n16549849 ANOTHERNAME" with 50 lines, as you said in the question. If you need to read the whole file, no matter how many lines it have, you can put some stop condition in the if(buffer[0] =='\0'). To remove the "No names[1]" and so on, you need to point to a file with 50 or more lines, or remove the respective printf, they are just outputs to help in the code understanding.